# SeekBar android lable

Tags: customview, android

Привет, я новичок в разработке под андроид, подскажите пожалуйста,
[как стандартный SeekBar превратить в это?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhDz0.png)

Заранее Спасибо.

Дополнение:

Нужно, что бы при смещении бегунка менялся текст на указателе и соответственно его расположение относительно положения бегунка. 
[Как-то вот так.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35913579/seekbar.png)

Answer (score 1):

Начните с этой [статьи](http://www.tutomobile.fr/realiser-une-progressbar-seekbar-personnalisee-sur-android-tutoriel-android-n%C2%B024/10/). Там текст правда на французском, но код то нормальный:)

Comment: Это немного не то, как сделать кастомный SeekBar я уже знаю, я вот не могу понять как на него лэйбл прицепить.

Comment: нужно было сделать акцент на то, что именно Вам нужно. Вариант первый - можно просто сделать прорисовку, но тогда элемент скорее всего будет занимать больше места. Если же это должно быть "как подсказка", тогда можно сделать дополнительный layout, который разместить поверх всех и правильно спозиционировать.

Comment: @KoVadim какой тонкий троллинг :) Для тех, кто не оценил тонкость:  *lable* - это почти как по французски *le bleu*

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь примитивный пример кода или какие-то ссылки?